# java parsing a string like "0:ADD(10)"

Tags: java, parsing

i am having a string array like this {"0:ADD(10)","1:ADD(20)"} how can i parse this and get the value '10','20' from this string ,

Scenario is : i am trying to write a **client and server** app using Apache Mina server , when i sent message between client and server i am getting response as "0:ADD(10)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression like this:

```
\\((\\d+)\\)
```

to extract the number from between the brackets. More information on java regex can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html)
Note: Since java adds, by default, the `^` and `$` at the beginning and end respectively, we have to add the `.*` before and after the pattern we want to match.

```
String[] str  = new String[]{"0:ADD(10)","1:ADD(20)"};
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*\\((\\d+)\\).*$");
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
        {
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str[i]);
            System.out.println(m.matches());
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
```

Prints:

> true
>
> 10
>
> true
>
> 20

Comment: thnkx for the reply , i had a doubt weather to use regex or not

Answer (score 2):

```
    String[] split = "{\"0:ADD(10)\",\"1:ADD(20)\"}".split( "," ); 
    for ( String e : split ) {
        String arg = e.substring( e.indexOf( '(' )+1, e.indexOf( ')') );
         System.out.println( arg );
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
int num = Integer.parseInt("0:ADD(10)".split("[()]")[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit of overkill, but this should work

```
    String input="{\"0:ADD(10)\",\"1:ADD(20)\"}";
    Pattern r= Pattern.compile(":ADD\\(([0-9]*)\\)");
    Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1)); //Result is here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
String digits=(digits=CharMatcher.DIGIT.retainFrom("0:ADD(10)")).substring(1,digits.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

this single line does the work:

```
String[] arr = str.replace("{", "").replace("}", "").replaceAll("\"\\d+:ADD\\((\\d+)\\)\"", "$1").split(",");
```